# How to remove days from previous/next month in month view

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

So as it says in the title, I got a task to make a calendar with events that were fetched and one of requests was that in monthly view only days of that month are visible (e.g. if selected month starts on wednesday, monday and tuesday from that first week aren't shown).

Using react-big-calendar I couldn't find a way to do that, only thing I managed to do was removing dates by writing css file that hides those dates, but events from those removed dates are still shown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set max and min dates.

```
<input type="date" id="start" name="trip-start" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-31" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you understood what I'm looking for? I'm using component Calendar in React